# Give a name to an XMLRootElement

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services, javabeans

This is my bean

```
package mypackage;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"columnName", "new_value"})
public class GetUserInfoResponse {

    private String columnName;
    private String new_value;

    @XmlElement(nillable = true, name = "nomChamps")
    public String getColumnName() {
        return columnName;
    }

    @XmlElement(nillable = true, name = "ValeurModifiee")
    public String getNew_value() {
        return new_value;
    }

}
```

And this is the result that i'm getting

```
{
  "getUserInfoResponse": [
    {
      "nomChamps": "AD_Client_ID",
      "ValeurModifiee": ""
    },
    {
      "nomChamps": "AD_Org1_ID",
      "ValeurModifiee": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm getting like a title `getUserInfoResponse` (name of the class java bean)

Now, i want to get a specific title (example `values` in the place of class java name)

like this
[image]

Comment: Tried setting the `name` on the `@XmlRootElement`?

Comment: yeah, i already try i't, it's not working @XmlRootElement(name="values")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its simple

```
@XmlRootElement(name="values")
```

Comment: What version of jaxb?

Comment: Try adding @XmlType(name="values")

Comment: jaxb-impl version 2.2.2 & jaxb-api 2.2.2

Comment: my fault, it's working now for @XmlRootElement(name="values"), i make a mistake now it's work, thanks man, i will validate your solution